# Bootstrap ui angularjs with filter issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in my angular application. I have a tooltip in the html page which works fine. I noticed that after the tooltip is displayed and I move my mouse out, the Ui-bootstrap-tpls.js fires a method called  "hideTooltipBind" which in turn calls $apply and it triggers the filters in that scope to reload.

Lets say I have 10 filters in the scope which is filtering an array of 100 each. Everytime a tooltip is displayed, all my filters are forced to reload again. How can I avoid this?
I am using

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js
jquery-2.0.3.js
ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js
```

I have attached the screenshot of the Call Stack

[image]

Comment: The tooltip directive actually creates a [separate scope](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L110) for the tooltip. Are you sure it causes *your* whole scope to be digested?

Comment: Yes,It triggers all watches and filter re-evaluation.

Comment: This is the response I got from the Bootstrap UI team  "This is how AngularJS works - any call to $scope.$apply will trigger all watches and filter re-evaluation. This has nothing to do with tooltips - you will see the same behavior when, for example, entering text into an input field."

Comment: You could probably create a directive with its own scope folding the filtered lists. Alternativley use the tooltip inside a directive causing only that part of the scope to be updated. When creating the directive make sure to us isolate for the scope.

Comment: @Gokul - you can limit the number of watches that will get re-evaluated per digest cycle by using a https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce - for static data that originates from a scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise some form of one-time binding. There are multiple options out there:

- [bind-once](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) by pasvaz
- [angular-once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) by tadeuszwojcik
- [watch-fighters](https://github.com/abourget/abourget-angular) by abourget
- [fast-bind](https://github.com/kasperlewau/fast-bind) by me (fork off of Karl Seamons work)

There are some differences to the four (unrelated to your question at hand however):

- **bind-once** is the most popular one seeing the most active development. Requires two directives to do the job (`bindonce` and `bo-*`).
- **angular-once** is the minimalist of the four (don't quote me on that).
- **watch-fighters** doesn't handle promise based data.
- **fast-bind** has a notifier system for semi-static bindings, using the event bus in Angular.

---

**Assuming** you'd start leveraging either one of them, your bindings could look something like this:

```
<div bindonce="someData">
  <span bo-bind="someData.text | yourFilter"></span>
</div>
```

---

```
<span once-text="someData.text | yourFilter"></span>
```

---

```
<span set-text="someData.text | yourFilter"></span>
```

---

```
<span bind-once="someData.text | yourFilter"></span>
```

This way, your filters would not reevaluate on Angular calls to `$digest`. If you are filtering a collection in your view (`<li ng-repeat="coll | filter"></div>`), I'd suggest you move those filters to the controller to reduce the amount of calls to the filters themselves.